JPA Criteria Api: Using alias from GROUP BY in SELECT
I need to aggregate some data by datetime intervals. The correct SQL string for my DB looks like:
select dttm_agg, count(id)
from table_name
group by DateTime::Format("%Y-%m-%d")(dttm) as dttm_agg;

It's important to not use convertation function in SELECT clause, so I have to use alias instead it.
How can I describe this query using CriteriaQuery?
Belowed code doesn't work, I don't know how to use alias name in multiselect
val cb = em.criteriaBuilder
val criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Any::class.java)
val root = criteriaQuery.from(TableName::class.java)

val alias = cb.function("dt_format", String::class.java, root.get<String>("dttm")).alias("dttm_agg") as Expression<*>

criteriaQuery.multiselect(
            alias,
            cb.count(root.get<String>("id"))
        )
            .groupBy(alias)


Try this on H2 database:
@Service
public class DateService {
    private final EntityManager em;

    public DateService(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Data
    static class MyResult {
        String dttm_agg;
        Long countId;
    }
    public void getAggIdByDate() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MyResult> cq = cb.createQuery(MyResult.class);
        Root<DateTable> root = cq.from(DateTable.class);

        Expression<String> dtf = cb.function("FORMATDATETIME", String.class, root.get("dttm"), cb.literal("YYYY-MM-dd"));
        Expression<Long> idF = cb.count(root.get("id"));
        CriteriaQuery<MyResult> fq = cq.multiselect(dtf.alias("dttm_agg"), idF.alias("countId")).groupBy(dtf);
        List<MyResult> r = em.createQuery(fq).getResultList();
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}

Or maybe you prefer this:
    public void getAggIdByDate() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
        Root<DateTable> root = cq.from(DateTable.class);

        Expression<String> dtf = cb.function("FORMATDATETIME", String.class, root.get("dttm"), cb.literal("YYYY-MM-dd"));
        Expression<Long> idF = cb.count(root.get("id"));
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> fq = cq.multiselect(dtf.alias("dttm_agg"), idF.alias("countId")).groupBy(dtf);
        List<Tuple> r = em.createQuery(fq).getResultList();
        r.forEach(t->System.out.println(t.get("dttm_agg")+":"+t.get("countId")));
    }

